# How to resolve method length()

Tags: java, arraylist

So I've been working on a program that will accept 5 names from the user and store it into an ArrayList called "name". The code that I'm working is provided by the question and I just need to complete it based on the question given.

[Question screenshot (provided for better context)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZM4K.jpg)

So, I have completed both of the questions given but encountered an error.

**My code:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Retrieve
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList name = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList value = new ArrayList();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    /* Question (a) */
    String a;

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        a = sc.nextLine();
        name.add(a);
    }

    name.add(2, "9");

    /* Question (b) */
    System.out.println("\n"+name);
    System.out.println(value);

    for(int i=0; i < name.size();i++)
    {
        String nm = (String) name.get(i);
        int num = name.length()*3;
        value.add(num);
    }
  }
}
```

**The error message:**

```
  java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method length()
  location: variable name of type java.util.ArrayList
```

So from my understanding after googling about this problem is that ArrayList only have `length` field and not `length()` which is the one provided in the question. I'm facing some difficulties given that IMO the part b) of the question that my lecture provided is not specific enough for me to understand because it only mentioned there "Draw the ArrayList objects name and value after the program has been
executed.". Based on that question, I assumed that the ArrayList `value` is used to count the number of elements inside the ArrayList `name` after the input entered by the user. I assumed that my lecturer demanded something like this

[ArrayList visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCfrX.png)

So I decided to write the code like this to visualize the ArrayList `name` and `value`.

```
/* Question (b) */
    System.out.println("\n"+name);
    System.out.println(value);
```

**The expected result would look somehting like this:**

```
[Muhammad ,Khadijah ,9 ,Aisyah ,Omar ,Fatimah]
[0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,4,5]
```

Feel free to give any suggestion or solution, criticism is most welcome given that I knew how some people would react to a "homework question" and understood the reason behind it and have tried my best to provide the necessary information but if there are some, I will take it openly.

**note:** Yes I've noticed the syntax error `impport` at the top and only the part where `/* Question (a) */` and `/* Question (b) */`sits is the part where I inserted my own answer. The rest is provided with the question above.

Comment: Read the javadoc for the class. It isn't called `length`.

Comment: You are actually looking for `ArrayList.size()` method.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the reply :) , will do

Comment: @nkrivenko thanks for the help :), I've tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noticed, `List`s don't have a `length()` method. However, [`String`s do](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#length()).

From reading the question it looks like it's a typo in the question, and it should have read `int num = nm.length()*3;`, but you'll have to ask your teacher to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mureinik, sure I'll ask my lecture for better context around this question.

Answer (score 1):

Arraylist is an Collection Object so it doesn't have

```
length()
```

method use

```
size()
```

instead

Comment: Thanks for the reply @user2483362, understood. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing the length of `ArrayList` in for loop as: `for(int i=0; i < name.size();i++)` but I don't know why you called `name.length()` inside the for loop.

`ArraysList` don't have length() method, to find the number of elements inside array you have to call `names.size()`;

But if you want to get the length of string (element of ArrayList) inside an `ArrayList` you have to call it like this: `name.get(i).length();`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mustafa Poya, As you can see based on the question that I've provided at the top, that part that you mentioned is one of the parts that is provided by the question itself and not written by me :)